# Django allauth does not find /accounts/login view due to "No module named path.to"

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I've installed django_allauth but the accounts/login view shows this error.

```
ImportError at /accounts/login/
No module named path.to
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://chew.local:5000/accounts/login/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named path.to
Exception Location: /Users/benbowler/Sites/Repositories/chew/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  /Users/benbowler/Sites/Repositories/chew/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.2
Python Path:    
['/Users/benbowler/Sites/Repositories/chew',
 '/Users/benbowler/Sites/Repositories/chew/venv/bin',
 '/Users/benbowler/Sites/Repositories/chew/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg',
 '/Users/benbowler/Sites/Repositories/chew/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/Users/benbowler/Sites/Repositories/chew/venv/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Users/benbowler/Sites/Repositories/chew/venv/lib/python2.7',
 '/Users/benbowler/Sites/Repositories/chew/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/benbowler/Sites/Repositories/chew/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Users/benbowler/Sites/Repositories/chew/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/benbowler/Sites/Repositories/chew/venv/Extras/lib/python',
 '/Users/benbowler/Sites/Repositories/chew/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Users/benbowler/Sites/Repositories/chew/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Users/benbowler/Sites/Repositories/chew/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/benbowler/Sites/Repositories/chew/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 16 May 2013 15:01:20 +0100
```

providers_media_js is red below:

```
Error during template rendering

In template /Users/benbowler/Sites/Repositories/chew/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/templates/socialaccount/snippets/login_extra.html, error at line 3
No module named path.to
1   {% load socialaccount %}
2   
3   **{% providers_media_js %}**
```

Comment: did you grep for `path.to` in your directory structure? It might be a copy paste error

Comment: Can you take a look in the setting at this point SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS. There you have to define a proper function and not path.to.callable. Take look here

https://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html?highlight=path.to#facebook

Comment: Take a look here https://speakerdeck.com/tedtieken/signing-up-and-signing-in-users-in-django-with-django-allauth?slide=55

Comment: @Azd325 Your solution works. If you post it as an answer, we can give you proper upvotes.

Comment: @Philipp Zedler I added a answer for it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at your settings. I think you did a copy paste fault:

This snippet what might cause this error is from https://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html?highlight=path.to#facebook

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
{
    'facebook':
    {
        'SCOPE': ['email', 'publish_stream'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        'LOCALE_FUNC': 'path.to.callable',
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False
    }
}
```

and I think your problem was in `LOCALE_FUNC` because you have to define there a proper function and not a path what not exists.

Here is some example for it. How it can be
Slideshare: https://speakerdeck.com/tedtieken/signing-up-and-signing-in-users-in-django-with-django-allauth?slide=55

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
{
    'facebook':
    {
        'SCOPE': ['email'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': { 'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        'LOCALE_FUNC': lambda request: 'en_US'
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I'm using Django 1.6 and followed the exact same tutorial but I get the `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` error when I use `'LOCALE_FUNC': lambda request: return 'en_US',` in my `settings.py`. I had to modify it to `'LOCALE_FUNC': lambda request: 'en_US',` for it work.

Comment: The return keyword is to be removed, it should be: 'LOCALE_FUNC': lambda request: ‘en_US’},